# How to handle delimiter with backslash in data

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

How do i handle `|` which is also a delimiter in my data,

Here is a sample field value,

```
|152| XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX.1001 0503~ADX\|0\|ZZ~NTE\|ADD\|XXXXXXXXXX/~SE\|40\|0060~GE\||
```

the value `XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX.1001 0503~ADX\|0\|ZZ~NTE\|ADD\|XXXXXXXXXX/~SE\|40\|0060~GE\` is a single field value but due to escaping the backslash, the values are moving to next fields.

I need to have the column value `XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX.1001 0503~ADX\|0\|ZZ~NTE\|ADD\|XXXXXXXXXX/~SE\|40\|0060~GE\` and it should not get split into multiple columns .How can I fix this.

`regexp_replace(col(c), "\\\\|", "\\\\\\\\|"))` is not working

Comment: you can read it as text and replace \| with another string and then split with | delimiter and change back the string to \| and then convert to dataframe

Comment: Can you show the sample input and output? I don't get the problem here and would appreciate some help :)

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I am having the character `\|` in column values, and if you can see the column delimiters is also '|', so I am looking for a way to read the file correctly

Comment: @RameshMaharjan How do i read the DF back with delimiters after I replaced '\|' with something else

Comment: @Arjun, I hope my answer below helps to solve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, if you have data in format as

```
152| XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX.1001 0503~ADX\|0\|ZZ~NTE\|ADD\|XXXXXXXXXX/~SE\|40\|0060~GE\||
```

Then, you should read it using *sparkContext's textFile* and replace `\|` with some other strings and then *split* with `|`, convert to `dataframe` and finally use `regexp_replace` function for replacing the converted string back to `\|`

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("path to the text file")
              .map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.replaceAll("\\\\\\|", "#%#").split("\\|", -1).toSeq))

val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("col1", StringType, true),StructField("col2", StringType, true),StructField("col3", StringType, true)))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

df.withColumn("col2", regexp_replace(col("col2"), "#%#", "\\\\\\|")).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+
|col1|col2                                                                               |col3|
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+
|152 | XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX.1001 0503~ADX\|0\|ZZ~NTE\|ADD\|XXXXXXXXXX/~SE\|40\|0060~GE\||    |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: well I did this. `val header = rdd.first
  val rows = rdd.filter(line => line != header)`

Comment: -1 is used to include the empty strings as well. usually all empty string at the end of split are ignored but -1 will include all of them

Comment: sorry to ask an additional question to this post, but since all the dtypes of the resultant df schema is String, how do I handle datetype or integer types?

Comment: use .cast("integer") to the column which you want to convert to integer type and then you can handle the datatype in integer

Comment: can i use .cast in the schema itself?

Comment: i am trying this but its not working, it says `cannot be applied to (String, org.apache.spark.sql.Column, org.apache.spark.sql.Column, org.apache.spark.sql.Column)`





`scala>  panel_df.select("TRANSACTION_ID", to_date($"TDATE", "yyyy-MM-dd").alias("TDATE"), to_date($"PDATE", "yyyy-MM-dd").alias("PDATE"), to_date
  ($"FCDate", "yyyy-MM-dd").alias
  ("FCDate")).show()`

Comment: `panel_df.select(panel_df("TRANSACTION_ID"), to_date($"TDATE", "yyyy-MM-dd").alias("TDATE"), to_date($"PDATE", "yyyy-MM-dd").alias("PDATE"), to_date ($"FCDate", "yyyy-MM-dd").alias ("FCDate")).show()` all datatypes should match. this should work

Comment: Thanks @Ramesh, One thing i would like to know. in the below line from your answer `val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("col1", StringType, true),StructField("col2", StringType, true),StructField("col3", StringType, true)))`, why can't I use another dtypes apart from String

Comment: I already tried it, but its resulting in an error. `Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.String is not a valid external type for schema of date`. is it because that the field also has nulls??

Comment: yes, one of the input data for the column is of type string and cannot be inferred as date. thats the problem

Comment: Hmmm.. so how can i handle it? can it be fixed while creating the rdd itself as in your answer

Comment: yes you can check for date regex and if fails and insert a valid date

Comment: inserting a valid date is not an option that i can do, can it be left blank?

Comment: a date field cannot be a blank date. Have you ever heard about a blank date????  better leave it as string then